# JavaScript - Is it possible to check multiple weekdays in one condition without using OR?

Tags: javascript

I want to shorten my following code:

```
if (d.getDay() == 1 && d.getHours() <= 21 || d.getDay() == 2 && d.getHours() <= 21 || d.getDay() == 3 && d.getHours() <= 21 || d.getDay() == 4 && d.getHours() <= 21 || d.getDay() == 5 && d.getHours() <= 21) {
    //do something
}
```

to something like this?:

```
if (d.getDay() == 1-5 && d.getHours() <= 21) {
    //do something
}
```

or even shorter. Is that possible and what is the best way? I use the line multiple times in my code and sometimes with little variation. And if possible without jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your `if` condition by using `>=` and `<=` operators,

```
var day = d.getDay();
var hours = d.getHours();
if ((day >= 1 && day <=5) && hours <= 21) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This will also work for any number between for example 1 and 2, e.g. `1.5f`

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz `getDay()` will not return `1.5`

Answer (score 1):

Shaving off a few keystrokes from Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy's answer:

```
var day = d.getDay();
var hours = d.getHours();
if (hours < [0,22,22,22,22,22,0][day]) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: That is, unless there are e.g. shorter opening times on friday, which are easier to implement in my variant.

Comment: The goal shouldn't always be to write shortest code. While your idea is brilliant, there is definitely a performance hit in your code, especially if the function is being executed frequently.